# What kind of mushrooms are these growing in the sun in Houston

Tags: mushrooms

Any guesses as to what kind of mushrooms these are. They were growing at the base of an old Oak tree stump in the bright sunlight. I've provided a number of different views. I'm located on Lake Houston in the greater Houston area.

Edit: I've now found these same mushrooms in several other areas of the yard, mostly growing in the lawn and also in some dirt patches, both in the sun and in the shade.

[image: Picture1]

[image: Picture2]

[image: Picture3]

Comment: I've seen mushrooms that look much like that growing in central NY. Not sure what they are.

Answer (score 1):

These are bit old and are already degrading, so it's difficult to decide precisely what they are. As they're associated with a rotting tree stump, from the colour and the fact they are conjoined at the base, I'd have said honey fungus, but absent is the creamy, yellow/white collar usually present beneath the gills on the stalk, though it's possible its degraded away already.

You could try a spore print by taking a cap and laying it gill side down on a sheet of paper and leave it for a day or two - if there are any spores left and
it's honey fungus, the spores should be creamy coloured, but the spores may have already dispersed.

Comment: There was a younger bunch of this mushroom and I compared some of these to pictures online. These mushrooms look a lot like honey fungus, but there are two differences. First, many of the pictures of honey fungus show a gradient of color on the cap, where the top of the cap is darker than the edges. These are uniform or are darker on the edge. The second is that the collar you referenced is absent completely. I'm going to assume that these are not honey fungus, but I greatly appreciate your taking the time to offer your suggestion. I will try to get a spore print, though it might be too late.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely to be chantrelles. References more often show orange color , but some show this type. I live north of Houston and this was a record year for chantrelles here. They will be associated with trees, likely the is a buried stump or nearby tree. If they are chantrelle , they are eatable . You could try eating a very small  sample ; they do not fit the description of any poison mushroom. ( Unfortunately , I cannot take my own advice , cancer has left me unable to taste or eat ). Formerly I did collect and eat several types of wild mushrooms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked at images of chantrelles, and there are many differences between these mushrooms and chantrelles. But thank you for taking the time to share.

Comment: Mushroom ID is not easy as they are more variable than plants.  The internet is convenient and helpful but  limited  . I believe they are chanterelle  but I cannot show you a picture in any of my several mushroom guides that looks exactly the same.  For example Audubon Guide for North American Mushrooms   lists 10 different  varieties of chanterelles with photos , but no very good match. The mushrooms  will be back !

Comment: And "mushroomexpert.com"  says there are 46 different species of the chanterelle group in  North America. And the spore print  of mine which are identical to your picture, is white to cream color.